# C multidimensional array pointing problem?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

Trying to take strings as input and place it in 2d array. Why is *this given code* showing different behavior. The last for loop "arr[i][j]" is not printing the string.It is not even printing a character also.

**Why this code does not work.only this code.Not a new way to write it**

This code takes input just fine(or at least the way needed.each row a single string no white space)And when a short string is stored remaining are filled with null after carriage return. When the arr[] is passed in last for loop everything seems fine only when arr[][] is passed ,the problem arises.But again arr[][] is initialized as arr[1][0] then arr[2][0] so should not it work!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void){
    int i,j,m;
    scanf("%d",&m);
    char arr[m][50];
   for(i=0;i<m;i++){
       for(j=0;j<50;j++){   
    printf("please enter a string");
    scanf("%s",&arr[i][j]);
/*j is always 0. arr[i] takes string without space and store ending with null*/
    break;
       }

    }
  //Everything fine upto this,including storing a small continuous string in arr[i](where i<50) and null terminating*/
    for(i=0;i<m;i++){
        for(j=0;j<50;j++){
        printf("%s\n",arr[i][j]);
        break;
    }

}
    }
```

Comment: 1. Why do you have a nested for loop and an unconditional break after that? 2. How many strings do you need to store? 3. to printf with %s you need to give the address of the array of characters, which you are not giving. 4. You do not have proper indentation.

Comment: I'd say the culprit is `scanf("%s",&arr[i][j]);`, that address, is not fit to store anything more than an empty-string.

Comment: @SouravGhosh but still it stores in strings. The problem is it is unable to print with that line of code.

Comment: Variable length array?

Comment: `char arr[m][50];` so `arr[i][j]` is type **char**, not `char*`. You are using `scanf("%s",&arr[i][j]);` which is attempting to store a string at the *address of* `arr[i][j]` (which is fine by *happy-accident* when `j = 0;` but then begins overwriting your prior string (offset by 1-char as `j` increments)). Further `char arr[m][50];` declares a VLA of `m` rows with `50` characters per-row. As `j` increases, the number of characters available for storage in the row decreases by the same amount.

Answer (score 5):

You program has several issues, like using wrong format specifier:

```
scanf("%s",&arr[i][j]);
```

`arr[i][j]` is a character and you are using `%s` format specifier. If you want your program should take string as input, you just need to do:

```
scanf("%s",arr[i]);
```

Since, you have given the size `50` characters, put a restriction in `scanf()` to not to read more than 49 characters (the remain one character space is for null terminating character) like this:

```
scanf("%49s",arr[i]);
        ^^
```

Beware with this, it does not discard the remaining input from input stream when the input characters are more than `49` and the remaining characters will be consumed by consecutive `scanf()` call.

If you want to drop the extra input which wasn't consumed by `scanf()`, one way of doing it is to read and discard the extra input using a loop, like this:

```
int c;
while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
    /* discard the character */;
```

In case if you have any doubt on *how this will discard the extra input*, I would suggest first go through [**getchar()**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar).

Putting all these together, you can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int i,m;
    scanf("%d",&m);
    char arr[m][50];

    for(i=0;i<m;i++){
        printf("please enter a string");
        scanf("%49s",arr[i]);
        int c;
        while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)  // <=== This loop read the extra input characters and discard them
            /* discard the character */;
    }

    for(i=0;i<m;i++){
        printf("%s\n",arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

**EDIT**

The below edit is because OP updated question and added - **Why this code does not work.only this code.Not a new way to write it**

Above in my answer, I have already stated that you are using wrong format specifier in the `scanf()`. In this part of your code:

```
for(i=0;i<m;i++){
   for(j=0;j<50;j++){   // <====== Nested for loop
printf("please enter a string");
scanf("%s",&arr[i][j]);  
// since the nested loop is supposed to run 50 times, assuming you are trying to read character by character and using %s format specifier
break;
// the nested loop will break in the first iteration itself unconditionally, do you really need nested loop here!
   }

}
```

Check the inline comments. Hope this might give an idea of the mistakes you are doing.

Seems that you want to read string character by character using `scanf()`. If this is the case than make sure to take care of null terminating character because, in C, strings are actually one-dimensional array of characters terminated by a null character `'\0'`.
You can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void discard_extra_input() {
        int c;
        while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
            /* discard the character */;
}

int main(void){
    int i,j,m;

    printf ("Enter number of strings: ");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    discard_extra_input();

    char arr[m][50];
    for(i=0;i<m;i++){
        printf("please enter string number %d: ", i+1);
        for(j=0;j<49;j++){
            scanf("%c",&arr[i][j]);
            if (arr[i][j] == '\n') {
                //need to add null terminating character manually
                arr[i][j] = '\0';
                break;
            }
        }
        if (j==49) {
            // In case where the input from user is more than 50 characters,
            // need to add null terminating character manually.
            arr[i][j] = '\0';

            // discard the extra input when input from user is more than 50 characters.
            discard_extra_input();
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<m;i++){
        for(j=0;j<50 && arr[i][j]!='\0';j++){
            printf("%c",arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf ("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The code is self explanatory except one thing - call to `discard_extra_input()` function after first input from user `scanf("%d",&m);`. Reason -
Look at the statement:

```
scanf("%c",&arr[i][j]);
```

the `%c` format specifier will consume the leftover newline character `'\n'` from the input stream due to the `ENTER` key pressed after first input by the user *(number of strings input from user)*. Hence, in order to discard it, calling `discard_extra_input()` function. In the other place it has been used to discard the characters when user entered string of size more than `49`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: A good answer; some comments about why `c` needs to be an `int`, and why it is necessary to test for `EOF` when clearing the input stream would make it even better.

Comment: @DavidBowling Thanks, added reference link for `getchars()`. Let the OP give some effort and try to understand it by himself. Also, removed unused variable `j` from the code.

Comment: @givil check the EDIT.

Comment: "scanf("%s",&arr[i][j]);  
// trying to read a character using %s format specifier." Apparently the small input string overwrites in arr[i] location (as it has upto 50 spaces). But then after carriage return all the rest (50-string length )is filled with null. and then the process repeats m times with different arr[i] values actually storing the strings in arr[i](where 0<i<50) and ending each string with null.

Comment: @givil `&arr[i][j]` -> `&(*(arr+i))[j]` -> `&(*(*(arr+i))+j)`. Now since you are breaking the nested loop in first iteration in which value of `j` is `0`. Hence, the expression for `j=0` will be - `&(*(*(arr+i))+0)` -> `&(*(*(arr+i)))` -> `(*(arr+i))` -> `arr[i]`. That means this statement - `scanf("%s",&arr[i][j]);` is equivalent to `scanf("%s",arr[i]);` **only when** `j=0`. Having the nested loop supposed to run for `50` times and breaking it in first iteration doesn't make any sense but making the code obfuscated.

Comment: bit.ly/2NrGwBa uploaded debug info have a look please. As you can see strings are properly stored and null terminated

Comment: @givil Read my previous comment carefully. I have mentioned the reason why they are getting stored properly and also **why this will happen only when `j=0`**.

Comment: what about printing them. Why can't it be printed with the printf("%s\n",arr[i][j]);

Comment: @givil Aren't you compiler giving you **warning** on this `printf(..`. Well, I will not go in much details. If you just want to make it work then - while printing you are missing `&`. Replace this `printf("%s\n",arr[i][j]);` with this `printf("%s\n",&arr[i][j]);`. Read may previous to previous comment. It also explains why this will **only** work when `j=0`.

Answer (score 1):

> I know the code. But looking for specific ans. Where the problem lies with the code

The problem is here:

```
  scanf("%s",&arr[i][j]);
```

and here:

```
printf("%s", arr[i][j]);
```

This is the specific answer you are looking for.

`%s` won't do any bound checking. It adds the characters starting from the memory location `arr + i * m + j` to `arr + i * m + j + (length of input) + 1` (one extra char for the additional null character that scanf appends). Take a sample input. Assume an arbitrary starting address for `arr` and do the maths. 
Also consider any writes beyond the allocated space for `arr` leads to [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Similarly `printf("%s", arr[i][j]);` will try to start reading from the **address arr[i][j]** till it finds a null character. It would usually lead to crash of the code because if your string has ascii characters, the address would be too low to point to any valid user-mapped memory. 
If your code is working, its mostly because you already have a UB in your scanf.

**Get a pen and paper and do some dry runs**

Comment: "%s won't do any bound checking. It adds the characters starting from the memory location arr + i * m + j to arr + i * m + j + (length of input) + 1 (one extra char for the additional null character that scanf appends).  "  Will it not stop at null character if found before array length?

Comment: Nope. scanf won't read the array. It will just write to it blindly.

Comment: problem is in the last loop. string is stored properly with \0.at end in every arr[i]. expecting printf("%s",arr[i]) to stop at \0 when looping.

Comment: Give a running example. You can use ideone.com to share the example.
With a test input sequence and the output you are getting.

Comment: bit.ly/2NrGwBa uploaded debug info have a look please.  As you can see strings are properly stored and null terminated

Comment: As expected your code is crashing in printf. If you look at the output you will see cygwin reporting the crash and creating the dump file.
Learn how to use a debugger, enabling first chance exceptions.
Just do printf("%s", arr[i]);

Comment: why is it crashing. Is not it supposed to print untill a \0 is found

Comment: Read last line from my answer.

Answer (score -1):

This is a pretty simple problem buddy. You've got the idea right actually, that you need to use 2d array to store strings. Just that the usage is slightly wrong.

First of all let me tell you how 2d arrays need to be used to store in c. In your 2-D array, you've got rows and columns. Say, row represented by `i` and columns by `j`, i.e, each row `arr[i]` contains `j` elements. So in your context, each row `arr[i]` contains each string of upto 50 chars. So `scanf` should be just for `arr[i]`. And you need to loop with `for`, `m` times to accept `m` strings.

Same applies to printing as well.

Here is the working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void){
    int i,j,m;
    printf("\nenter m value:");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    char arr[m][50];
   for(i=0;i<m;i++){ 
    printf("\nplease enter a string no %d: ", (i+1));
    scanf("%s",arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\nthe strings are: \n");
    for(i=0;i<m;i++){
      printf("\n%s\n",arr[i]);
    }
}
```

And the output in case you want to cross check:

> OUTPUT:
>
> enter m value: 3
>
> please enter a string no 1:  qwerty
>
> please enter a string no 2:  asdfgh
>
> please enter a string no 3:  zxcvbn
>
> the strings are:
>
> qwerty
>
> asdfgh
>
> zxcvbn

Comment: I know the code. But looking for specific ans. Where the problem lies with the code.

Comment: Yes buddy, I get it. Read my complete answer @givil. I've mwntioned how the `scanf` and `printf`  should actually be given.